# Data pre-processing for input data when clustering with CLUTO

Tags: perl, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, cluto

I am trying to clustering some words based on their similarities(between two words)
Some part of my data is as below (it's just example "animal.txt", it's similar with adjacency matrix).

```
    cat dog horse ostrich 
cat  5    4    3    2
dog  4    5    1    2
horse 3   1    5    4
ostrich 2  2   4    5
```

The bigger number means that the similarity between two words is higher. Based on this kind of format data, I want to make a clusters. (for example, if I want to make 2 clusters then the result will be (cat, dog), (horse,ostrich)).

I tried to use CLUTO... to make some clusters.

At first, I have to re-construct the input file before doing CLUTO clustering. 
So, I used the doc2mat (http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/files/fs/sw/cluto/doc2mat.html).. but I don't know how I can use this properly for making CLUTO input files (like mat, label files) And after making CLUTO input files, then how I can make clusters based on above data?

Comment: What data you want to see on the output of the preprocessing script?

Comment: After pre-processing with doc2mat, I want mat file, and column, row files. Those are the input for CLUTO.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are an adjacency matrix, the corresponding CLUTO input file is a so-called *GraphFile*, not a *MatrixFile*, and thus `doc2mat` doesn't help.

This program `txt2graph.pl` converts a file like your example "animal.txt" to a *Graph File* and a *Row Label File*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@F = split ' ', <>;             # begin reading txt file, read column headers
($GraphFile = $ARGV) =~ s/(.txt)?$/.graph/;
$LabelFile = $GraphFile.".rlabel";
open LABEL, ">$LabelFile";
open GRAPH, ">$GraphFile";
print GRAPH $#F+1, "\n";        # output number of vertices=objects=columns=rows
while (<>)
{                               # process each object row
    @F = split ' ', $_, 2;      # split into name, numbers
    print LABEL shift @F, "\n"; # output name
    print GRAPH @F;             # output numbers
}
```

After the CLUTO clustering is done, this program `pclusters.pl` prints the result in your desired output format:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
($LabelFile = $ARGV[0]) =~ s/(.clustering.\d+)?$/.rlabel/;
open LABEL, $LabelFile; chomp(@label = <LABEL>); close LABEL;   # read labels
while (<>)
{
    $cluster[$_] = [] unless $cluster[$_];      # initialize a new cluster
    push $cluster[$_], $label[$.-1];            # add label to its cluster
}
foreach $cluster (@cluster)
{
    print "(", join(', ', @$cluster), ")\n";    # print a cluster's labels
}
```

The whole procedure is then:

```
> txt2graph.pl animal.txt
> scluster animal.graph 2
> pclusters.pl animal.graph.clustering.2
```